# Comma separated values list in pgfkey is not a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, comma-separated-list

The question might be dumb but I can't find an adequate solution.

If I put a comma separated value list as parameter using *pgfkeys*, then the result of *pgfkeysvalueof* is an atomic value and not a list.

The code (that is not working) is this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    shapes.arrows,
    shapes.multipart,
    shapes.callouts,
    shapes.misc,
    tikzmark,
    arrows, 
    positioning,
    calc,
    math,
    scopes,
}

\tikzstyle{every entity} = []
\tikzstyle{entity} = [shape=rectangle, draw, black,  thick,
                      minimum width=6em, minimum height=3em,
                      every entity]

% \usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\newcommand{\rol}[3][type=normal,arcfmt=--,card=N,total=false]{
\pgfkeys{/incoMer/.cd,
startPoint/.initial={-},
endPoint/.initial={},
arcfmt/.initial={--},
rolname/.initial={},
rolnameParams/.initial={},
card/.initial={N},
cardpos/.initial={above},
#1,
}

\draw [-] (#2) \pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/arcfmt} node[pos=0.80,\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/cardpos}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/card}} 
            node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/rolnameParams}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/rolname}} (#3);
}

\title{prueba}
\begin{document}
% Comienza el Mer
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Entidad Estudiantes
\node[entity](st){Students};

\node[entity][left=5cm of st](cs){Courses};

\rol[%
    arcfmt={edge[bend left,sloped]},
    rolname={very very very long test},
    rolnameParams={below,sloped},
    %rolnameParams={below},
    ]{st}{cs};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

When the *rolnameParams* line is changed by commenting the line and removing the % in the next line, it all works fine.

The error is:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/below,sloped' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

It must be noted that the *arcfmt* parameter works fine but if the same strategy is used for the node, it doesn't work.

Why is this and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

The parser for the list of PGF keys in the optional argument of `\node` looks for the comma separators before expanding anything, therefore in your case `\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/rolnameParams}` is considered to produce (after expansion!) a single PGF key, hence the error message.

I propose to use a style here (named `/incoMer/impl/rolnameParams@style`), and define this style from key `rolnameParams` of the optional argument of `\rol` using `\pgfqkeys{/incoMer}{#1}`, where `rolnameParams` is itself a style that defines `/incoMer/impl/rolnameParams@style` using its argument:

```
rolnameParams/.style={/incoMer/impl/rolnameParams@style/.style={#1}}
```

The same holds for `cardpos`, which is also used to produce a list of PGF keys. Other things:

- I improved the structure;
- don't use the long-obsolete `\tikzstyle`—use `\tikzset` and the `.style` `pgfkeys` handler instead;
- don't use `;` after your own macro calls (this causes the warning `Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!` in your example);
- please write a [**minimal** example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317) next time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  every entity/.style={},
  entity/.style={
    shape=rectangle, draw, black, thick,
    minimum width=6em, minimum height=3em, every entity},
}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /incoMer/.cd,
  arcfmt/.initial={--},
  rolname/.initial={},
  card/.initial={N},
  % Styles
  impl/cardpos@style/.style={above},
  cardpos/.style={/incoMer/impl/cardpos@style/.style={#1}},
  impl/rolnameParams@style/.style={},
  rolnameParams/.style={/incoMer/impl/rolnameParams@style/.style={#1}},
}

\newcommand*{\rol}[3][type=normal,arcfmt=--,card=N,total=false]{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/incoMer}{#1}%
    \draw [-] (#2) \pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/arcfmt}
      node[pos=0.80, /incoMer/impl/cardpos@style]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/card}}
      node[/incoMer/impl/rolnameParams@style] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/incoMer/rolname}}
      (#3);
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[entity] (st) {Students};

\node[entity, left=5cm of st] (cs) {Courses};

\rol[%
    arcfmt={edge[bend left,sloped]},
    rolname={very very very long test},
    rolnameParams={pos=0.3,below,sloped},
  ]{st}{cs}                 % don't end this with ';'

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]